# QT on windows mobile

Tags: qt, windows-mobile

How are QT applications developed for Windows mobiles ?? Is it worth to do  ??

Answer (score 3):

How? - See http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-windows-ce

Is it worth it? - If you're building cross platform with QT and want to support Windows Mobile then it seems a sensible way to go.  If you only want to target Windows Mobile, I'd develop directly with Microsoft tools (inside Visual Studio).